# Count of IDs at a specific status at various set time intervals

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Im trying to create a histogram to identify situations where there are a large number of 'ID's which have the status "CASTING" simultaneously.

You will notice I have a rank column present - I have attempted this problem in a number of ways, the most recent was to partition over the IDs, convert the event_time column to the nearest 15 min interval by rounding down and then counting the number of IDs with the "CASTING" status by interval. Unfortunately, this doesn't get me where i need to be, as it simply sums the instances of the status change, rather than a running current total by including those that were at 'CASTING' prior to the specific time interval.

I lack direction on how to generate a list of the 15 min time intervals between
14:00 and 17:30 (if this is even possible?!) - not overly necessary as i can resort to hardcoding them in and the perhaps performing some kind of join to the list.

I think i've been staring at this problem for so long, that i cant see the obvious solution... Is anyone able to provide a high-level outline on what method i can use to achieve the desired results below?

Here is a test dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` varchar(1), `loc` int, `status` varchar(7), `date` datetime, `event_time` datetime, `rnk` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `loc`, `status`, `date`, `event_time`, `rnk`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 'READY', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 15:39:00', 1),
    ('A', 1, 'CASTING', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 14:09:00', 1),
    ('A', 1, 'QUEUED', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 12:59:00', 1),
    ('B', 1, 'READY', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 23:59:00', 1),
    ('B', 1, 'CASTING', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 13:52:00', 1),
    ('B', 1, 'QUEUED', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 13:44:00', 1),
    ('C', 1, 'READY', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 17:59:00', 1),
    ('C', 1, 'CASTING', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 14:59:00', 1),
    ('C', 1, 'QUEUED', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 11:59:00', 1),
    ('D', 1, 'READY', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 13:59:00', 1),
    ('D', 1, 'CASTING', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 12:59:00', 1),
    ('D', 1, 'QUEUED', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 11:59:00', 1),
    ('E', 1, 'READY', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 21:51:00', 1),
    ('E', 1, 'CASTING', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 18:59:00', 1),
    ('E', 1, 'QUEUED', '2019-08-04 00:00:00', '2019-08-04 11:59:00', 1)
;
```

My output should look something like this:

```
Date    Count_at_casting
08/04/2019 14:00    1
08/04/2019 14:15    2
08/04/2019 14:30    2
08/04/2019 14:45    2
08/04/2019 15:00    3
08/04/2019 15:15    3
08/04/2019 15:30    3
08/04/2019 15:45    2
08/04/2019 16:00    2
08/04/2019 16:15    2
08/04/2019 16:30    2
08/04/2019 16:45    2
08/04/2019 17:00    2
08/04/2019 17:15    2
08/04/2019 17:30    2

Id  loc status  date                START               END
A   1   CASTING 08/04/2019 00:00    08/04/2019 14:09    08/04/2019 15:39
B   1   CASTING 08/04/2019 00:00    08/04/2019 13:52    08/04/2019 23:59
C   1   CASTING 08/04/2019 00:00    08/04/2019 14:59    08/04/2019 17:59
D   1   CASTING 08/04/2019 00:00    08/04/2019 12:59    08/04/2019 13:59
E   1   CASTING 08/04/2019 00:00    08/04/2019 18:59    08/04/2019 21:51
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output does not match your input - I assume that is just a sample.  Following is for oracle.  [from dual] in oracle is to just select 1 row and first with is to simulate input.  Oracle to_char and to_date convert strings to date.  Similar functions are available in sqlserver along with datepart type of functions

```
[
with table1 as (
select 'A' id, 1 loc, 'READY' status, to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') datetime, to_date('2019-08-04 15:39:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') event_time from dual union all
select 'A', 1, 'CASTING', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 14:09:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'A', 1, 'QUEUED', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 12:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'READY', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 23:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'CASTING', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 13:52:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'B', 1, 'QUEUED', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 13:44:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'C', 1, 'READY', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 17:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'C', 1, 'CASTING', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 14:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'C', 1, 'QUEUED', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 17:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'D', 1, 'READY', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 13:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'D', 1, 'CASTING', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 12:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'D', 1, 'QUEUED', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 11:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'E', 1, 'READY', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 21:51:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'E', 1, 'CASTING', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 18:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  from dual union all
select 'E', 1, 'QUEUED', to_date('2019-08-04 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2019-08-04 11:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
),
table1_with_rounded_min as
(
    select y.*,
           to_date(to_char(event_time,'YYYYMMDDHH24') || ltrim(to_char(event_round_15)),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') event_time_round15
    from
    (
        select x.*,
               trunc(x.event_min / 15)*15 event_round_15
        from
        (
            select table1.*, to_char(event_time,'MI') event_min
            from table1
        ) x
    ) y
)
select to_char(event_time_round15, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') date1, 
       sum(case when status = 'CASTING' then 1 else 0 end) Count_at_casting
from table1_with_rounded_min
group by event_time_round15
order by 1
]
```

Comment: Hi Saad, thanks for the contribution.

However, this solution is similar to one of my previous attempts - where it is simply summing the count of status = 'CASTING' at each interval. What i'm aiming for is a running total of status = 'CASTING', using the timestamp of a 'CASTING' line to denote the beginning, and the end of a 'CASTING' line being the next status update for that particular ID.

Comment: What should be the output for the exact input in your example?

Comment: I have corrected the expected output to match it to the schema information - i must have miscalculated it in the first attempt. Thanks again Saad!

Comment: Can u explain how count increased at 14:15 and 14:30?  I assume 14:09 is 14:00 for rounding so 1st makes sense.  Please put a comment with your result explaining why is that count increasing.  Also the time range - is that independent.  i.e. for example if your table is empty - you still expect that many rows?  Because your data set does not have all the times

Comment: I added in an extra table at the bottom that i extracted from the main table, providing a start and end time for the 'casting' using the start time of that status and the start time of the next status. @ 14:00 - the only ID that is active is B. Then by 14:15, both B and A are active. Ideally my output has the same exact list of intervals per day, but if there are no id's active, then the value would be zero. Let me know if you need any further clarity!

Comment: Why did you not mention that casting is a session between cast time and READY time?  And at 14:00 time which ids are you thinking are casting and which ones at 14:15? Is 14:09 counted in 14:15 or in 14:00?  In your first table where you put expected result - in another column show which rows from second table are getting counted.